# How to find filepath of open MS Access file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have MS Access Switchboard created by my self and trying to figure it out how to find the filepath of the same one when it is open. For example if it is open in Desktop to get C:\Desktop and etc.
I really do not know if it is possible at all, but if someone have an idea how to do it in MS Access vba would be very helpfull.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use this to get current path file in vba

```
dim currentPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
dim currentFileName = CurrentProject.Name
dim fullPath = currentPath & currentFileName
```

Comment: madmxg That worked fine but I needed to read the name file too :(, I just realize that my question was wrong in first place. So I need C:\Desktop\switchboard 01.accde

Comment: and use CurrentProject.Name to get a file name property